# Java - Only dispose JFrame on close?

Tags: java, swing, dispose

In my Java program I would like that, regardless of any other windows being open, whenever the user clicks the red X in the corner, **just that** swing frame closes. I experimented with JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE and other window listeners, but when I exit one JFrame the system still exited.

To clarify, suppose I have two JFrames visible, exiting one automatically exits the other, and the system exits. Any ideas as to how to only close one JFrame? Thanks.

Comment: if the only frame running is disposed, the system will exit after a small period of inactivity.

Comment: Robert- the system still exits even if other frames are open, closing them as well, which is my issue at hand.

Comment: Maybe you still have a `WindowListener` calling `System.exit()`?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have EXIT_ON_CLOSE set, like: frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

Answer (score 7):

This works for me:

```
public class Test {

    public static class TestFrame implements Runnable{
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(200, 300);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new TestFrame());
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new TestFrame());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write out a test - I had a WindowHandler redundantly exiting the system when I clicked X, overriding the defaultCloseOperation. Do I need to do anything more to close this question?

Comment: If you accept an answer (including your own), people will probably stop answering it... but nothing closes it - so that other people can also learn from the answer, and indeed any future answers.

Answer (score 0):

Finnw was correct - I set a new WindowListener (although it never called System.exit() unless it does by default) but I can handle it moving forward now. Thank you all

Comment: You need to click the tick next to the correct answer to accept the reply as answer